# Calculate Total Monthly Sales per Branches including Month without Sales in MSSQL (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

As the title says. I want to calculate the total monthly sales per branches.

Each `Branch` has `Monthly Target`(quota)

I have this db schema:

```
`Sales.Branch`
 - Id
 - Name

Sales.BranchTarget
- Id
- BranchId
- Month
- Year

Sales.Transaction
- Id
- Date
- BranchId

Sales.TransactionItem
- Id
- Pages
- Rate
```

I want to have a result that displays TotalSales of every branch per month including the months without `Transaction` as long as there is a `Target` for them.

Here is the result that I want
[image]

On the image, If I added Target for the Branches from Jan - Mar 2016
I still should see March even without Transaction or the month is a future month.

I have this query, but it doesn't return months without Transaction

```
select 
    b.Name,
    SUM(ti.Pages * ti.Rate) as TotalSales,
    SUM(ti.Pages) as TotalPages,
    bt.Amount,
    bt.Month,
    bt.Year
 from
    Sales.BranchTarget bt
        left join Sales.[Transaction] t on bt.BranchId = t.BranchId
        left join Sales.TransactionItem ti on ti.TransactionId = t.Id
        left join Sales.Branch b on b.Id = t.BranchId
where 
    MONTH(t.Date) = bt.Month
    AND YEAR(t.Date) = bt.Year
group by  bt.Month, bt.Year, bt.Amount, b.Name
order by bt.Month, bt.Year, b.Name
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: as Bhavesh Harsora's query answer

```
select 
    b.Name,
    SUM(ti.Pages * ti.Rate) as TotalSales,
    SUM(ti.Pages) as TotalPages,
    bt.Amount,
    bt.Month,
    bt.Year
from Sales.BranchTarget bt
left join Sales.[Transaction] t
    join Sales.Branch b 
        on b.Id = t.BranchId    
    on bt.BranchId = t.BranchId
    AND MONTH(t.Date) = bt.Month
    AND YEAR(t.Date) = bt.Year
left join Sales.TransactionItem ti 
    on ti.TransactionId = t.Id  
group by  bt.Month, bt.Year, bt.Amount, b.Name
order by bt.Month, bt.Year, b.Name
```

But and the result is

[image]

`(almost there, just the NULL branch name)`

Any advise would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to move your `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause. And you need to summarise TransactionItem up to monthly _before_ you join to it, otherwise you'll get double counting on the targets.

Comment: can you please show me? I've tried different solution, but due to my limited sql knowledge, Im having hard time dealing with syntax errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is modified query:

```
 select 
    b.Name,
    SUM(ti.Pages * ti.Rate) as TotalSales,
    SUM(ti.Pages) as TotalPages,
    bt.Amount,
    bt.Month,
    bt.Year
from Sales.BranchTarget bt
    left join Sales.[Transaction] t
        on bt.BranchId = t.BranchId
        AND MONTH(t.Date) = bt.Month
        AND YEAR(t.Date) = bt.Year
    left join Sales.TransactionItem ti 
        on ti.TransactionId = t.Id  
    left join Sales.Branch b 
        on b.Id = bt.BranchId 
group by  bt.Month, bt.Year, bt.Amount, b.Name
order by bt.Month, bt.Year, b.Name
```

Comment: Your answer worked with a little modification. instead of Sales.Branch and Sales.Transaction, I've joined the Sales.Branch and Sales.BranchTarget. Please see my update to see your query result. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer worked with a little modification. instead of Sales.Branch.Id = Sales.Transaction.BranchId, I've joined the Sales.Branch.Id = Sales.BranchTarget.BranchId. Please see my update to see your query result. Thank you!